# how long is iAd review time

Tags: iad

I just released my first app to the app store. I received a message saying that the iAd is not under review. Is there a common time frame for iAd to be reviewed? I know for Apps it is around 6-8 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My App was just in review for 4 hours and then went live with the "Ready for Sale" status. iAds have started to serve in the App within about one hour after the time it hit "Ready for Sale" status. This was my first time implementing iAds in the App.